# Sax Parsing in encoded tag

Tags: java, android, saxparser

I have xml Like:

```xml
<OuterTag>

    <InnerTag>

        <content:encoded><![CDATA[Huawei have entered the smartphone race by unveiling their own quad core devices and the Chinese...<br/>
        <br/>
        </div>]]>

        </content:encoded>

    </InnerTag>

</OuterTag>
```

I can Get all the value from simple tags, but i can not get from `<content:encoded>`, How can I solve it?

Comment: u want to parse content:encoded tag & get data from that tag?

Comment: start element:
if (localName.equals("content:encoded")) {

   contentOn = true;
   channelparse=false;

  }

character:
 if (contentOn==true && channelparse==false) {

    contentValue = new String(ch, start, length);

    contentOn = false;
   }

end element:

if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")&& channelparse==false) {

    data.setcontent(contentValue);

   }

get:

public ArrayList<String> gotcontent() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return data.getcontent();
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem lately, instead of content:encoded use encoded in your code.

```
if (localName.equals("encoded")) // not content:encoded
```

Answer (score 0):

check this it might solve u r problem

StringBuilder stringBuilder;

```
start element: 
       if (localName.equals("content:encoded")) 
       {
        contentOn = true; channelparse=false; 
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       }
       character: 
       if (contentOn==true && channelparse==false) 
       { 
         contentValue =""; 
         contentValue = new String(ch, start, length); 
         stringBuilder.append(contentValue);
         contentOn = false; 
       } 
      end element: 
      if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")&& channelparse==false)
       { 
        data.setcontent(stringBuilder.toString()); 
       }
      get: public ArrayList<String> gotcontent() 
     { 
      return data.getcontent(); 
     }
```